# How to turn the value of a variable into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have an input in tkinter where a date is entered in the format of dd/mm/yyyy . I would like to make a variable equal to the three letter version of the month and another to be equal to the yyyy of a month.

the input variable is date_entry and I've tried

```
ss_date = date_entry.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

and

```
ss_date = (datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%d/%m%Y"))
```

but i keep getting module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

I've looked online but every example uses datetime to generate an example in the first place, I cannot find any explanation of how to extract it from a variable value.

````
```
ss_date = date_entry.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") and
ss_date = (datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%d/%m%Y"))
```
````

module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Can you please help.

Comment: eg. date_entry ="28/01/2019" I want to be able for a variable to equal Jan and the other to equal "2019"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you import datetime correctly. Python has a library `datetime` which then also has a `datetime` object in it. So either import the object version directly, or call it by the 'full name' (`datetime.datetime`).

Object version:

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_entry = "04/05/2019"
datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

'Full name' version:

```py
import datetime
date_entry = "04/05/2019"
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%d/%m/%Y")
```